# Uploading content to AWS3 error on Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-s3, xcode13

> Error uploading file: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed.
> (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 4.)")

Some errors that are related to this error commonly are the PoolID and bucket not in same region. or mismatch in iOS versions.

I have checked that my identityPoolID and bucket are of same region.
my bucket is also set to public

my Macos ver is 12.1 hence in my Podfile I included: platform :ios, '12.1'

Gist of my code:

```
let bucketName = "bucketpublic"
var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
let link1 = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/hello/Desktop/pink.jpeg")

func uploadjsonfile(Url: URL, type: String){   //1
            
            let key = "rkey"
        
            let expression  = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
            expression.progressBlock = { (task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask,progress: Progress) -> Void in
              print(progress.fractionCompleted)   //2
              if progress.isFinished{           //3
                print("Upload Finished...")
                
              }
            }
            
            expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-acl")   //4
            expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl")

            completionHandler = { (task:AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if(error != nil){
                    print("Failure uploading file")
                    
                }else{
                    print("Success uploading file")
                }
            } as? AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock
            
            
            //5
            AWSS3TransferUtility.default().uploadFile(Url, bucket: bucketName, key: String(key), contentType: type, expression: expression, completionHandler: self.completionHandler).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
                if(task.error != nil){
                    print("Error uploading file: \(String(describing: task.error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
                if(task.result != nil){
                    print("Starting upload...")}
      
                return nil
            })
        }
```